# mysql хитро перезаписать базу

Tags: mysql

так немного предыстории:
Работал сайт, с него снят бекап.
На бекапе были произведены доработки и настройки.
Но пока был этап разработки работал старый сайт, пополнял товары получал заказы и пользователей.

Теперь снял бекап базы с работающего сайта и мне надо как то хитро ее вгрузить на сайт который в разработке (но так что бы она не удалила старую таблицу и вставила новую, а как бы по строкам проверяла и если есть совпадение то перезаписала на последнюю(но токо строку) а тех которых не нашла оставила как есть).

Надеюсь объяснил задачу, помогите найти оптимальное решение.

Comment: Структуры менялись?

Comment: @Akina нет, изменилось несколько сотен строк и добавилось 2 таблицы.

Comment: Эти доработки и настройки нужно было сохранять в виде миграций, чтоб потом накатить эти миграции на живую базу (почитайте в интернете что это)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно делать дамп базы, при помощи `mysqldump` со следующими параметрами

- `--no-create-info` - не добавлять в дамп операторы `CREATE TABLE`
- `--replace` - вместо оператора `INSERT` в дамп добавлять операторы `REPLACE`

Если вы меняли еще и структуры таблиц, тогда добавьте в создание дампа ключ `--complete-insert`. Он добавит в дамп еще и имена полей

Comment: ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 2539: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 
выдает ошибку во время вгрузки базы, как решить?

Comment: Значит вы меняли еще и структуры таблиц. Добавляли или удаляли поля. Тогда добавьте в создание дампа ключ `--complete-insert`. Он добавит в дамп имена полей

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Для программистов. Написать скрипт, который построчно проверяет наличие строк по первичным ключам и добавляет элементы, которых нет. Или принимает решение о перезаписи по какому-то алгоритму

Вариант 2. Найти инструмент синхронизации БД. Под винду, знаю, это делает SQLYog (платный)